# Maths on multiple fields on seperate lines using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I've been doing some maths on a 3 field x 2 line file like this:

```
3216.01   2724.81   1708.25
1762.48   617.436   1650.79
```

My question is how do i refer to the first field on the first line and in the same calculation, refer to the first field in the second row?

And just for completion: I'm planning on taking $1 (line1) and minusing $1 (line2), then squaring and doing the same for the other columns and finally summing this value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this line works with your requirement:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i}
NR==2{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=(a[i]-$i)^2; printf "sum: %.3f",s}' file
```

result:

```
sum: 6557076.288
```

**Note**

- this should work with dynamic number of columns, but exactly two lines
- the output format is `%.3f`, you could change it if you like
- The codes could be shorten, since there are two similar for-loop structures

**EDIT**

as suggested by EdMorton, the above codes could be written as:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a)}
    NR==2{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=(a[i]-$i)^2; printf "sum: %.3f\n",s}' file
```

very good suggestion, I didn't think of the split... thank Ed!

Comment: +1 but you can replace `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i` with `split($0,a)` and you should probably print a newline at the end of the output.

Answer (score 3):

I would normally story it in some temporary variable

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1-a} {a=$1}' inputfile
```

Comment: `I'm planning on taking $1 (line1) and minusing $1 (line2), then squaring and doing the same for the other columns and finally summing this value.`

Comment: @Kent "My question is how do i refer to the first field on the first line and in the same calculation, refer to the first field in the second row?"