# awk help in modifying a semi csv file to a new format

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I am stuck with a small problem and cant get my head to work it out,

I have a file, which has several lines like this :

```
fig|1671.3.peg.2935,fig|1671.3.peg.2936,fig|1671.3.peg.29370 operon1
```

I want something like this:

```
fig|1671.3.peg.2935    operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.2936    operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.29370    operon1
```

the file does not have fixed number of comma separated elements, in this case it was 3 and other cases there are sometimes 1 to 8.

Thanks in advance.
CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should do what you want:

```
$ awk -F '[, ]+' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i, $NF}' file
fig|1671.3.peg.2935 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.2936 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.29370 operon1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {print $i,$NF}}' <filename>
```

You can specify a regular expression as a separator. `-F '[, ]` tells awk that either of `,` or  (space) can be the separator. The rest is pretty obvious. `NF` is the number of fields, and `$NF` is the last field.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Ed Morton's recommendation about split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332269/maths-on-multiple-fields-on-seperate-lines-using-awk/18332514#comment26908555_18332514):

```
$ awk '{split($1, a, ","); for (i in a) {print a[i], $2}}' file
fig|1671.3.peg.2935 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.2936 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.29370 operon1
```

#### Explanation

- `split($1, a, ",")` splits the string based on comma. So an array `a[]` will be created.
- `{for (i in a) {print a[i], $2}}` loops through the array printing the element + 2nd field of the input file.

Note that it works for any number of comma separated amount of fields:

```
$ cat file
hello,how,are,you good!
$ awk '{split($1, a, ","); for (i in a) {print a[i], $2}}' file
hello good!
how good!
are good!
you good!
```

Comment: `awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=0;++i<NF;)print $i,$NF}'` this time it is shorter without `split` :)

Comment: Uhms, you are right @Kent! It is clear I was looking forward to using it :)

Comment: @Kent is right, split() isn't buying you anything in this case. Also, that `for (i in a)` loop could rearrange the order of your fields which is probably undesirable. Odd syntax on Kent's suggested replacement loop though - `for(i=0;++i<NF;)` seems less clear and obvious than the usual `for(i=1;i<NF;i++)` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/,(.*\s(\S+))/ \2\n\1/;P;D' file
```

On each line replace a `,` by a space and the last string on the line followed by a  newline and the remainder of the line. Print then delete up to and including the introduced newline and repeat until no further `,`'s are found.

Answer (score 1):

An awk version, with no loop.

```
awk '{gsub(/,/," "$2"\n")}1' file
fig|1671.3.peg.2935 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.2936 operon1
fig|1671.3.peg.29370 operon1
```